# Current location in SKOBBLER map

Tags: android, skmaps, currentlocation

I am new to android and even newer to Skobbler sdk
I am trying to access the current location but it taking me to berlin
I am using the code below :

```
mapView.getMapSettings().setCurrentPositionShown(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getCurrentGPSPosition` on SKMapSurfaceView to get the current position (either matched to the road network or not).

Check also the documentation: http://developer.skobbler.ro/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSurfaceView.html#getCurrentGPSPosition(boolean)

Alternatively you can listed to position update via [SKCurrentPositionListener](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.0/com/skobbler/ngx/positioner/SKCurrentPositionListener.html)